# Revoke a users authorization for the Instagram API

Tags: authentication, instagram-api

I'm trying to add a feature to my application that will revoke Instagram's API permission for a specified user. Is this possible with the Instagram API?

Comment: Not possible to revoke API permission for a single, would be a cool feature to have.

Comment: @krisrak that's weird, it seems like it's something a lot of people would want to do. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted this for long time, I have a paid instagram product, would be cool to revoke after they have canceled, cause some people pay and subscribe, copy access_token and cancel, and then they make API call directly and abuse the API on my app behalf.